# SQL Server building a dynamic 'To' string for email

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working a report that sends the results to a user and optional cc to the users management
Like 
Manager, Director, VP, etc

I've created several variables that are populated with the users management based on management role or level.

Example

```
Declare @EmailSM AS VARCHAR(300)
Declare @EmailRCM AS VARCHAR(300)
Declare @EmailDM AS VARCHAR(300)
Declare @EmailISM AS VARCHAR(300)
Declare @EmailIAE AS VARCHAR(300)
Declare @StackholdersCC as VARCHAR(500)
```

I want to assign @StackholdersCC with the email addresses of everyone that should get a copy of the email.

What are some suggestions on how to ensure there is a (;)semicolon between any addresses?

If the user only wants to cc his/her store manager then @StackholdersCC will = @EmailSM
But if the user wants to cc his/her store manager and the regional manager then @StackholdersCC will = @EmailSM + ';' + @EmailRCM

Thanks
Steve

Comment: You would add a semicolon just like you did. Not really sure what the question is.

Comment: I don't think there is one, @SeanLange . Seems the OP is asking and answering a question in a question. :/